# Getting a typescript class recognized as an interface

Tags: typescript, knockout.js, typescript-typings

When trying to upgrade to TypeScript 3.5 I encountered a problem with a signature that of some strange reason has been ignored by the ts-compiler, but have been there for years.

A third party framework (knockoutJS) requires me pass in something that complies to this:

```
interface ViewModelFunction {
    (params?: any): any;
}
```

Apparently runtime-wise it works with doing something like this:

```
class MyClass {
  public foobar: string;
  constructor(params: { foo: string; bar: number }) {
    this.foobar = params.foo + params.bar;
  }
  public doSomething = () => {
    return this.foobar.length;
  }
}
```

and then sending MyClass into a function that requires ViewModelFunction as an attribute. Since the code works, this is mostly a typescript issue. While it is a mystery (but not important why) ts3.5 suddently notices this, no version of typescript would accept something like

```
class MyClass implements ViewModelFunction{...}
```

So is it any way of converting the Class into the ViewModelFunction-interface?

Comment: Are yo sure it's not the knockout definitions that have changed ? This has been an error since at least 2.4: https://typescript-play.js.org/?ts=2.4.1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGrAgdwLIHsAmEANgGICuICYwuIyA3gFDIvIAUADnFHALYDOAfgBcyOCACeASlHiJAbkYBfRowRE4-fsmwSAwhq3JgvDkQi8I4beix5CpClRogmLDmQBGRYAmQxcXE9uUX4wKFAAc0UWBFowqDIqXChObj5+UXp-QNDwqPlkYKhREDJeT2hkJSkGZlYwAAtgfgA6AKDuZABeZC4eAXbA5ABqPvTB4pjq+o9vX2R8XABlXEsmqJ72Wu6APjrWZCgIMDIoOg22juLW8xBIpumVJSA

Comment: Yes. it is a result of union-improvement in TS3.5 I think. For a more accurate example see:
https://typescript-play.js.org/?ts=3.3.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgNIgPYINYYK5gDCGAtgA4YgTgDOyA3gFDIvJQQDmwNkUAFAkoxgHAFxpMOfEVIUq4ACoBPMhBoA6YiGEdkAHwlZcBYuUrUwy1RoCi5MEq06AlOIBuGYABMA3IwC+jIxeEAgANnDsyCBwJGpkiCjoRtKmchZWagzMrKC88EjITiLZrGXIbsAQAO4AshghYQD84gBqVXUNEGEAYnggCGDAlH5lgWV50AUodmQOxbpMYzksk7CJyO019Y19A0OUpeUsfAlQsTQtyHAgSq7Xt6OsgYGM4XA0dLWOEZ9HLIIQDwoHhBhh+GcLuIbncji8gm9KDxkJAeABeASyczgcTJKQmLHyMA0ZzINEAPiOgjMRPU7C4PGgfHolW2XTC4m+hF+NH8zgCCKAA

Comment: Can you please give a [mcve] so I can see what you're talking about?  I'm very confused how `MyClass` as shown would ever implement `ViewModelFunction`, so maybe I'm missing something.  You can likely silence the warning by using [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html), as in `interface MyClass extends ViewModelFunction {}`, but I'm afraid to suggest that because it seems dangerous.

Comment: yes in my comment above is link, You can chose ts-version from the dropdown at the top, it starts to fail with 3.5.

Comment: The code should be in the question and not a comment (you can edit the question). Anyway it looks like you are passing the class *constructor* to something that accepts only a `ViewModelFunction`... but that really should be an error. If I you try to call a constructor like a function you are likely to get an error like `TypeError: class constructors must be invoked with |new|` at runtime.  Ideally you should make an actual `ViewModelFunction` instance like `(x:any)=>new MyClass(x)` and use that instead of `MyClass`. Does that help? Or if not, can you show how it's supposed to work? Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const viewModel: ViewModelFunction = params => new MyClass(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move `doSomething` and public `foobar` to an interface and have a function that creates objects that implement both that interface and `ViewModelFunction`.

```
interface ViewModelFunction {
  (params?: any): any;
}

interface MyClass {
  foobar: string;
  doSomething(): number;
}

interface MyF extends MyClass, ViewModelFunction {}

function getMyF(foobar: string): MyF {
  const res = () => {yourViewModel();};
  res.foobar = foobar;
  res.doSomething = () => foobar.length;
  return res;
}
```

Comment: I need to send in something that matches _ViewModelFunction_ into another function. I don't think this workaround changes that in any way.

Comment: The result of `getMyF` does match `ViewModelFunction`.

Comment: And it's not a workaround, it's actually the valid solution to creating a function that also has methods.

Comment: `const getViewModel = (): ViewModelFunction => (params) => new MyClass(params);`
This simple solution seems to do the trick. No need to reimplement the functions.